# How to run an swift app in background when close app?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, background

I want some information stored in the database server if disconnected the Internet stored database sqlite when Internet connection to send data to the server (even when the app is closed) What is your suggestion for the job

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done, your application will work for just a short time in background after you terminate the application.

Read more about the [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on Apples Developer site.

Answer (score 2):

iOS app can't run on background. You can handle changes of connection (wifi , 4g, none) when app is on foreground. Or you can add background task which gives you additional time to save data into database etc.

Method is called beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: in applicationDidEnterBackground. More documentations is here Executing Finite-Length Tasks : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html